# How do I make icon and text go beside each-other in an Ionic ion-segment-button using CSS?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying the get an icon and text to go beside eachother in the ion segment button. I am trying to float the text left, but this is not working.

I am currently using the float one div method, are there any other methods that I can try?

this image is what I am currently getting in the view. [image]

But I want to achieve something along the lines of this , where the text is beside the image. 
[image]

HTML

```
 <ion-toolbar style="width: 100% !important" color="medium">
<ion-segment (ionChange)= "segmentChanged()" [(ngModel)]="segment" color="dark">
  <ion-segment-button value = "0">
    <ion-icon id ="heart" name="heart"></ion-icon><p id="Wipped">Wipped</p>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="1">
    <ion-icon name="heart-half"></ion-icon><p id="Wipping">Wipping</p>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>
```

SCSS

```
ion-segment-button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}


#Wipped {
  width: 300px !important;
  float:left !important;
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}

#heart {
  border: 1px solid green !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: fwiw, I'd look at the rendered html and see how things are being styled.  What you are showing is typical of having `block` styled items where `inline` styled items are expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :-

```
<ion-toolbar style="width: 100% !important" color="medium">
<ion-segment (ionChange)= "segmentChanged()" [(ngModel)]="segment" color="dark">
  <ion-segment-button value = "0" layout="icon-start">
    <ion-icon id ="heart" name="heart"></ion-icon><p id="Wipped">Wipped</p>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="1" layout="icon-start">
    <ion-icon name="heart-half"></ion-icon><p id="Wipping">Wipping</p>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>
```

add only `ion-segment-button` with `layout="icon-start"`